RGB values dropped after projecting SpatRaster
As stated in the title, after running project() on a .tif file with RGB layers, the values are dropped and only NAs are returned when plotting. The closest to a solution I found is here and here, but in both cases values persisted after project() (albeit in a modified form).
I tried various project() options, including projecting individual layers, to no avail. I suspect a different class type is required? However, I could not find anything in the documentation, or any definitive GitHub bug reports.
A repex:
library(basemaps)
library(terra)
library(sf)

# Create sf for SpatRaster extent
df  <- data.frame(lon = c(170, 172),
                  lat = c(-43, -45))

sf_poly <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), 
           crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_transform(3857)

r <- basemap_raster(ext = st_bbox(sf_poly)) %>%
  as("SpatRaster")

r
# class       : SpatRaster
# dimensions  : 1012, 728, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 305.7481, 305.7481  (x, y)
# extent      : 18924279, 19146864, -5621485, -5312068  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
# source      : basemap_20240418094850.270686.tif
# colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3
# names       : red, green, blue
# min values  : 167,   161,  162
# max values  : 255,   255,  255

Method 1: Project full SpatRaster
r4326 <- project(r, "EPSG:4326")
r4326 <- project(r, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
r4326 <- project(r, crs("EPSG:4326"))
r4326 <- project(r, "EPSG:4326", method = "bilinear")
r4326 <- project(r, "EPSG:4326", method = "near")
r4326 <- project(r, "EPSG:4326", align = TRUE)
r4326 <- project(r, "EPSG:4326", mask = TRUE)

r4326
# class       : SpatRaster
# dimensions  : 881, 882, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.002268062, 0.002268062  (x, y)
# extent      : 169.9997, 172.0001, -44.99879, -43.00063  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

Method 2: Project individual SpatRaster layers
r_list <- split(r, 1:nlyr(r)) %>% `names<-`(names(r))

r_list[[1]]
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 1012, 728, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 305.7481, 305.7481  (x, y)
# extent      : 18924279, 19146864, -5621485, -5312068  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator 
# source      : basemap_20240418094850.270686.tif 
# name        : red 
# min value   : 167 
# max value   : 255

r1 <- r_list[[1]] %>% project("EPSG:4326")

r1
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 881, 882, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.002268062, 0.002268062  (x, y)
# extent      : 169.9997, 172.0001, -44.99879, -43.00063  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)


I was about to write I cannot reproduce this because my result of project(r, "EPSG:4326") looked quite ok - but then this started to fail suddenly after the first successful try. Restarting R allowed me to reproject the raster once, but never a second time without losing values. This is wild. Bug?

@dimfalk, reproducible asks the question, feature or ...? and likely Robert would be interested. I followed as my attempts generally fail to carry through on first try as above, but perhaps I haven't been so scrupulous in my counting of 'one', 'two'. Seems worth a report. Perhaps a presumed 'writeRaster' after project and not relying on an object but I speculate wildly.

Still not sure why this fails, but at least I could narrow this down to basemap_raster(ext = st_bbox(sf_poly)) %>% as("SpatRaster"). Maybe some transient files not available anymore after some processing? Just guessing.
But if you use basemap_terra() instead, all of your project() versions did provide RGB values without any NAs.
library(basemaps)
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.8.2, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# Create sf for SpatRaster extent
df <- data.frame(lon = c(170, 172),
                 lat = c(-43, -45))

sf_poly <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), 
           crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_transform(3857)

r <- basemap_terra(ext = st_bbox(sf_poly))
#> Loading basemap 'voyager' from map service 'carto'...
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1012, 728, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 305.7481, 305.7481  (x, y)
#> extent      : 18924279, 19146864, -5621485, -5312068  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) 
#> source      : basemap_20240418151816.750852.tif 
#> colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
#> names       : red, green, blue 
#> min values  :  65,    92,  120 
#> max values  : 254,   248,  246

r4326 <- project(r, "EPSG:4326")
r4326
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 881, 882, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.002268062, 0.002268062  (x, y)
#> extent      : 169.9997, 172.0001, -44.99879, -43.00063  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
#> names       : red, green, blue 
#> min values  :  65,    92,  120 
#> max values  : 254,   248,  246


Completely missed the library(basemap) above. Interesting first dive here, as the as('SpatRaster') should make explicit the terra target (or I would have assumed so).

@Chris: This also fails with terra::rast() instead and also without piping, so maybe something with the raster brick object returned by basemap_raster() is wrong?

I think we simplify by taking basemap out of the chain (as I didn't have it till just now), and so my follow/comment was based simply on terra and wondering why, like @l-tyrone my values seemed dropped on project, which I assumed was something I was doing wrong, but was assuming values would be applied across the projected target.. That said, this may just be procedural to be addressed in ?, or may be function of underlying code. You spotted it, your report.

Dang, doesn't seem to be a way to get you to 1,111, you'll have to edit queque more to explore the odd numbers.

basemap, in their readme implies a call equivalence between basemap_raster() and basemap_terra(), but I think this still lives with terra.

@Chris: In order to keep this minimal, we could also use system.file("ex/logo.tif", package = "terra") |> rast() as RGB raster but I'm not able to reproduce said behaviour using this data... That's why I was increasingly confident that this is about {basemaps} in the end. Still wondering for whatever reason this fails for you.

Based on your answer, I found the source of the issue. You, @Chris, and most of all me will be kicking ourselves: basemap_raster() requires the raster package to be loaded! Given you were unable to replicate the issue, I believe the issue might lie in the GDAL, GEOS, and PROJ bindings. Pretty sure I had to implement some fix back in the day. Either way, upvote and accept for pointing the way.

@LTyrone: Fabulous! :) Let me mention this tiny fact in the answer then - in case someone does not read all the comments down here.

@dimfalk - was hoping you would :)

@LTyrone: I was just about to - but somehow this is still failing for me, even with library(raster) before basemaps::basemap_raster(). Same behaviour - it does work once, but not twice.

@dimfalk - time to ditch basemap_raster() altogether I think. It's not working for me on the second attempt now either. I'll file a bug report.
